# MySQL Filtering rows from three tables

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say i've got this database:

```
book
| idBook | name     |
|--------|----------|
|      1 |Book#1    |

category
| idCateg| category |
|--------|----------|
|      1 |Adventures|
|      2 |Science F.|

book_categ
| id     | idBook | idCateg  |   DATA |
|--------|--------|----------|--------|
|   1    |      1 |       1  | (null) |
|   2    |      1 |       2  | (null) |
```

I'm trying to select **only** the books which are in category 1 **AND** category 2
This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT book.* FROM book,book_categ
WHERE book_categ.idCateg = 1 AND book_categ.idCateg = 2
```

Obviously, this giving 0 results becouse each row has only one `idCateg` it does work width `OR` but the results are not what I need. I've also tried to use a join, but I just can't get the results I expect.
Here it's the SQLFiddle of my current project, the data at the begining is just a sample.
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e6bc/26)
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could double join with a constraint on the category id:

```
SELECT a.* FROM book AS a
INNER JOIN book_categ AS b ON a.idBook = b.idBook AND b.idCateg = 1
INNER JOIN book_categ AS c ON a.idBook = c.idBook AND c.idCateg = 2
```

You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT a.* FROM book AS a
WHERE
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT idCateg) FROM book_categ AS b
     WHERE b.idBook = a.idBook AND b.idCateg IN (1,2)) = 2
```

If you are on MySQL as your fiddle implies, you should prefer the join variant, since most joins are much faster in MySQL than subqueries.

### edit

This one should also work:

```
SELECT a.* FROM book a
INNER JOIN book_categ AS b ON a.idBook = b.idCateg
WHERE b.idCateg IN (5, 6)
GROUP BY idBook
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.idCateg) = 2
```

and should be faster than the two above, although you have to change the last number according to the number of category ids you are requesting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I just got one question. I'll be using the double joins, and in many cases, they will be more than two, maybe even 5. Is this OK? or isn't there a better way to do it?

Comment: I would use the joins. Add an index on `book_categ (idCateg, idBook)` and it will be efficient. (@GhostGambler, fixed a minor error in the join code.)